# Make columns using P tag and CSS

Tags: html, css

I need to make columns using a `p` tag.
Because the content is inserted via content manager, it creates a `p` element with the contents inside a box that i create.

I can't create 2 or more divs, like i said, the content is inserted inside a `p` element

How can i do that? Is there any CSS way to do it?

NOTE: columns like magazines or newspaper columns

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to modify the CSS for the p element and give him a width and float?

something like:

```
p {
   width: 300px;
   float: left;
   margin-left: 10px;
}
```

well, you got the idea :)

Comment: just what I was going to post

Comment: :) hope this solves his problem

Comment: i just did it, take a look at this:
`p {width: 200px;
float: left;
margin: 9px 0 0 27px;
}`
the box:
`#box {
width: 896px;
height: 500px;
float: left;
clear: both;
position: relative;
}`, the `p`content is overflowing the div `#box`, i dont know what im doing wrong

Comment: paste the html part also please

Comment: because the <p> part works, but I don't get where and how you have your #box item

Comment: `<div id="box">
    <a href="" class="close"></a>
    <img src="img.jpg" alt="" title="" />
    <em>02.JAN</em>
    <p> --- ADDED CONTENT HERE ---</p>
</div>`

Comment: I don't get it... look here and tell me what should it look like for you? http://cristic.koding.com/test/test.html - or give me a link to better understand your needs

Answer (score 0):

You can

[CSS Multi-column Layout Module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/)

[caniuse.com/#search=column](http://caniuse.com/#search=column)

In a more old-school way :

```
p.column {
    float:left;
    width : (100 / nbr of columns)%
    /* 33.3% for 3 columns */
}
```